# Aggregation function- two constrains on different features in data frame

Tags: r

How can you edit the aggregation function so that the output would answer two different function on different features?

To be specific, if I have many rows of samples and I want to find the row in which variable A has the maximum value but variable B has the minimum (A and B are a part of the same data frame).

If I use twice the aggregation function on each function I obviously get two rows, but I need one that give me the combination.

Comment: Try `df1[with(df1, A== max(A) & B == min(B)),]`

Comment: If the min(B) and max(A) aren't on the same row, then you would expect to receive two rows, correct?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible demo data frame of your issue.